# Compact spaces where not all compact subsets are closed

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness, examples-counterexamples

A topological space $(X,\tau)$ is called $C-C$ iff  the closed sets in $X$ coincide with the compact sets in $X$.

A topological space is called a $US$-space provided that
each convergent sequence has a unique limit.

We know that a topological space $C-C$ is compact and $T_1$, because singleton sets are compact.

> (1): Is there an example of a compact $T_1$ space that is not $C-C$ ?
>
> (2): Is there an example of a compact $US$ space that is not $C-C$ ?

Comment: For the first one, take any infinite set in the cofinite topology--the empty set and the sets with finite complements are open. I'll have to think on the second one (the first example I thought of wasn't compact, only Lindelof).

Answer (score 2):

1. Let $X$ be any infinite set, and let $\tau$ be the cofinite topology on $X$. Then $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is compact and $T_1$, and every subset of $X$ is compact, but the only closed sets in $X$ are the finite sets and $X$ itself, so $X$ is not $C$-$C$.
2. Let $X=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\cup\{0,p\}$, where $p$ is a non-principal ultrafilter on $\Bbb Z^+$. Points of $X\setminus\{p\}$ have their usual nbhds. For each $A\in p$ let $B_A=\{p\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in A\right\}$, and take $\{B_A:A\in p\}$ as a local base at $p$. $X$ is compact, because every nbhd of $0$ contains all but finitely many points of $X$. If $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ is a convergent sequence in $X$, then either $\sigma$ is eventually constant, in which case it has a unique limit, or it converges to $0$, so $X$ is $US$. Finally, $X\setminus\{p\}$ is a compact subset of $X$ that is not closed in $X$.

Comment: (1): which application has non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{Z}$ here?(2) what do you mean "**(a ): Points of X∖{p} have their usual nbhds.**"? and (b ): **$\{B_A:A\in p\}$ as a local base at $p$**?

Comment: @Alireza: (1) I don’t understand this question; I simply use the ultrafilter to define a nbhd base at $p$. (2) $X\setminus\{p\}$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$, so it inherits a topology from the usual Euclidean topology on $\Bbb R$; that subspace topology is the one that I’m talking about. ‘$\mathscr{B}$ is a local base at $p$’ means that every member of $\mathscr{B}$ is an open nbhd of $p$, and a set $U\subseteq X$ is a nbhd of $p$ if and only if there is a $B\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $B\subseteq U$.

Comment: In part of $T_B$ space you give an example from one point compatification of rational number to say Cartesian product of $T_B$ space do not need be $T_B$ , so is it right for $C -C$ spce, I mean the Cartesian product of $C - C$ space do not need be $C - C$? what do you mean about $B( K,\varepsilon)$? and why $I_\varepsilon - K \not= \emptyset$?

Comment: @Alireza: A space $X$ is $C$-$C$ if and only if it is compact and $T_B$. The one-point compactification of $\Bbb Q$ is compact and $T_B$, so it’s $C$-$C$, but its square is not $T_B$, so its square is not $C$-$C$. // Is that last bit a question about my earlier answer? If so, please give me a link and repeat the question there.

Comment: I can not link that. I have to repeat it:"The product of two $KC$ spaces need not be $KC$. Let $\Bbb Q^*$ be the one-point compactification of the rationals; then $\Bbb Q^*$ is $KC$, but $X=\Bbb Q^*\times\Bbb Q^*$ is not. It's well-known that $\Bbb Q^*$ is $KC$. To see that $X$ is not, let $\Delta=\{\langle x,x\rangle:x\in\Bbb Q^*\}$.

Comment: Then $\Delta$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb Q^*$, so $\Delta$ is compact; I'll show that $\Delta$ is not closed in $X$ and hence that $X$ is not $KC$ .Let $p=\langle\infty,0\rangle\in X$. For each $\epsilon>0$ let $I_\epsilon=(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\cap\Bbb Q$. For each compact subset $K$ of $\Bbb Q$ and $\epsilon>0$ let $B(K,\epsilon)=(\Bbb Q^*\setminus K)\times I_\epsilon$, and let $\mathscr{B}$ be the family of all such $B(K,\epsilon)$; $\mathscr{B}$ is a local base at $p$.

Comment: . Fix $B(K,\epsilon)\in\mathscr{B}$. Clearly $I_\epsilon\setminus K\ne\varnothing$, so let $y\in I_\epsilon\setminus K$; then $\langle y,y\rangle\in\Delta\cap B(K,\epsilon)$, and since $B(K,\epsilon)$ was arbitrary, it follows that $p\in(\operatorname{cl}_X\Delta)\setminus\Delta$ and hence that $\Delta$ is not closed.